# Custom Policy SMS Message

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I have a custom policy with MFA using PhoneFactor, it works however, the SMS sent says

```
123456
Use this code for Custom Policy Manage verification
```

Is there anyway to change the

> Use this code for Custom Policy Manage verification

to be different text? Say

> Use this code for X Application verification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently it is not possible to customize the SMS content.

You can raise user voice for your request in [Azure feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory?category_id=160596) portal or vote for the [existing one](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/36296983-azure-b2c-should-allow-to-customize-the-text-messa)

Comment: Thought that would be it. Shame, as if it even just used the application name it would be better that “Custom Policy”. Thanks

Comment: I've added a new request here https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/40973341-application-name-in-mfa-sms-when-using-custom-poli